# Zoom In & Zoom Out buttons - highcharts

Tags: highcharts, zooming

I have custom zoom buttons(Zoom In, Zoom out) in bubble chart. When user clicks on Zoom in button, Zooming should happen from left to right in the chart.  Similarly Zoom out should happen in this way, in contrary to the reset zoom functionality where zoom out happens instantly.

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/abcdlearner/dz4awe0y/
  /**
 * A Highcharts plugin to display the tooltip in a separate container outside the chart's
 * bounding box, so that it can utilize all space available in the page.
 */

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'getLabel', function(proceed) {

    var chart = this.chart,
      options = this.options,
      chartRenderer = chart.renderer,
      box;

    if (!this.label) {

      this.renderer = new H.Renderer(document.body, 0, 0);
      box = this.renderer.boxWrapper;
      box.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '-9999px'
      });
      chart.renderer = this.renderer;
      proceed.call(this, chart, options);
      chart.renderer = chartRenderer;

      this.label.attr({
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      });
      this.label.xSetter = function(value) {
        box.element.style.left = value + 'px';
      };
      this.label.ySetter = function(value) {
        box.element.style.top = value + 'px';
      };
    }
    return this.label;
  });

  H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'getPosition', function(proceed, boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
    var chart = this.chart,
      chartWidth = chart.chartWidth,
      chartHeight = chart.chartHeight,
      chartPlotWidth = chart.plotWidth,
      chartPlotHeight = chart.plotHeight,
      pos;
    point.plotX += this.chart.pointer.chartPosition.left;
    point.plotY += this.chart.pointer.chartPosition.top;

    // Temporary set the chart size to the full document, so that the tooltip positioner picks it up
    chart.chartWidth = $(window).width();
    chart.plotWidth += chart.chartWidth - chartWidth;
    chart.chartHeight = $(document).height();
    chart.plotHeight += chart.chartHeight - chartHeight;

    var pos = proceed.call(this, boxWidth, boxHeight, point);

    chart.chartWidth = chartWidth;
    chart.plotWidth = chartPlotWidth;
    chart.chartHeight = chartHeight;
    chart.plotHeight = chartPlotHeight;

    return pos;
  });

  /**
   * Find the new position and perform the move. This override is identical
   * to the core function, except the anchorX and anchorY arguments to move().
   */
  H.Tooltip.prototype.updatePosition = function(point) {
    var chart = this.chart,
      label = this.label,
      pos = (this.options.positioner || this.getPosition).call(
        this,
        label.width,
        label.height,
        point
      );

    // Set the renderer size dynamically to prevent document size to change
    this.renderer.setSize(
      label.width + (this.options.borderWidth || 0),
      label.height + this.distance,
      false
    );

    // do the move
    this.move(
      Math.round(pos.x),
      Math.round(pos.y || 0), // can be undefined (#3977)
      point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - pos.x,
      point.plotY + chart.plotTop - pos.y
    );
  };

}(Highcharts));


$('.container').each(function(i, v) {
  $(v).highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      inverted: true,
      borderWidth: 1
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Tooltip outside the box'
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
    },

    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Really, really long series name 1',
      data: [1, 4, 2, 3]
    }, {
      name: 'Really, really long series name 2',
      data: [4, 2, 5, 3]
    }, {
      name: 'Really, really long series name 2',
      data: [6, 5, 3, 1]
    }, {
      name: 'Really, really long series name 2',
      data: [6, 4, 2, 1]
    }]

  })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [axis.setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes) method to zoom in to a specific area.

```
$('#zoom').click(function() {
  chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1327449600000,1422144000000, false)
  chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(10, 20)
```

example https://jsfiddle.net/nhajopys/

Comment: I would use a linear axis instead of datetime where 1 = 1 year interval from now. Then you can increase/decrease min/max by 1. https://jsfiddle.net/urqcwsnp/