# Highchart general drawing svg label zoom-in on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I have a svg label which i am drawing using highchart general drawing. I want to know is there any way i can give an option for zoom in to that label on mouse hover.
Below is the code for label.

```
ren.label('PhantomJS', 210, 82)
                .attr({
                    r: 5,
                    width: 100,
                    fill: colors[1]
                })
                .css({
                    color: 'white',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                })
                .add();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the rest of your chart is built and what, if any, data live there.

Highcharts has a method to zoom to a specific point, but you need to define what that point is: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#zoomTo. You're drawing a label after the chart has been rendered, so it's not part of the chart's data, and therefore, there's no "point" you can zoom to.

Another alternative you could try is triggering the `setExtremes()` function to update the chart axes and "zoom" in on a particular area of the chart (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis%23setExtremes). See the linked fiddle in this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44875178/2596103. What they did here is use an HTML button that lives outside the chart vs. a rendered label.

You may want to consider annotations (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations) and see whether they can get you the zoom feature you're seeking.

I hope this information is helpful.